# Checking whether a NSLayoutConstraint has been applied or not

Tags: ios, uitextview, autolayout

I have a UITextView subclass that has a height constraint with priority 500. All other constraints in the view it's inserted in have 1000 priority, therefore when constraints can't be satisfied this one is the one that gets dropped.

I want to be able to verify if it was dropped or not in order to enable scrolling in that case.

I tried to verify it this way:

```
- (void)updateConstraints
{
CGSize size = [self sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(self.bounds.size.width, FLT_MAX)];

if (!heightConstraint) {
    heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:0 multiplier:1.0f constant:size.height];
    heightConstraint.priority=500;
    [self addConstraint:heightConstraint];
}
else heightConstraint.constant=size.height;
[super updateConstraints];

if (self.bounds.size.height!=heightConstraint.constant) {
    self.scrollEnabled=YES;
}





}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I think about the layout calls/callbacks order:

- `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` <-- constraint is calculated/applied immediately
- `[self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints]` <-- bottom-up, measure/calc; invokes `updateConstraints`
- `[self.view setNeedsLayout]` <-- top-down, applies solutions for constraints
- `[self.view setNeedsDisplay]` <-- top-down, render to screen

Sounds like you want to implement `- (void)updateConstraints` on your view, and add your logging and debugging there. Make sure to call `[super updateConstraints]`, or you're going to have a bad time. By the time that method exits, your constraints have been calculated.

Comment: Already tried that option... same behaviour. after the call to [super updateConstraints] view bounds haven't been recalculated yet...

Comment: That's *definitely* were the constraints are calculated. Make sure that you are checking the correct UIView that would have had the constraints applied (i.e. the one you think it is v. the parent that actually got them, for e.g.).

Comment: I updated the question with my updateConstraints implementation... what happens is that last if is true every single time the function executes. I'm quite sure bounds are calculated afterwards... this was my first approach...

Comment: Consider NSLog'ng or break-point'ng the values of `self.bounds.size` as well as `[self constraints]`. You should see the constraint in there. If it's not added or changed after the call to `[super updateConstraints]` returns, it's not going to be (in this pass through).

Comment: Oh, and finally: it's good habit to call `[fooView layoutIfNeeded]` if you need to create calculated, relative constraints (e.g. 1/2 a frame size or something) or you need to branch behavior based on calculated size. Granted, doing your check after the super's call *should* have the same results in most cases. I'd consider calling `[self layoutIfNeeded]` after `heightConstraint` is modified, check the size to have your scroll behavior, and the call super's method last. Calling `layoutIfNeeded` too often in undesirable, but it's often necessary in specific cases like this.